# How to prove that two groups are isomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I am unsure how to do this question please help.

Let $G$ be the subset of M$_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ defined by

$G = \left\{ \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & t & t^{2}/2\\
0 & 1 & t\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right):t\in\mathbb{R}\right\} $ .

i) Prove that $(G, X)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ ?.

Comment: "Unsure how to do this" does not say anything about what you have difficulty with. Your questions will be better received if you say something more concrete.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive criticism, Im still getting my legs with the site.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**.  If we call the matrix in your question $M(t)$, use ordinary matrix multiplication to show that
$$M(t)M(s)=M(t+s)\ .$$